# Grid resize content of 2 children to match the biggest one

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to make a box with 2 children that should have the same width, the problem is that those boxes have different content which determine the width of those.

How can i make those 2 boxes to have the size of the bigger one in a responsive way?

[image]

Here is the German version of the box, this one has the biggest difference in the width.
Note: the border is comming from Firefox feature.

i tried this with different values in the place of 50%

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(2, minmax(50%, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
```

I tried to achieve this using Grid but i did not succeed.

Comment: Confusing. Do you want the size to be equal or it should be of the biggest content width?

Comment: repeat(2, 1fr) should do it

Comment: @m4n0, I think OP wants both: The width of each column would be the width of the wider column (so the whole grid width would be approximately 2X the width of the wider column)..

Answer (score 0):

that was my mistake, i had this i the parent what was cousing the issue.

```
  width: min-intrinsic;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: min-content;
```